# Downloading a dynamically generated SVG file from the browser

Tags: html, svg

If I create an image using HTML SVG element, can I then offer this as an **SVG** file download to the user. For example I may want to load an SVG image, apply some basic transformations to it, add some text, then let the user download the result as a vector image.

Is that possible? I have been doing something similar with Canvas but have been struggling creating a vector image. I wasn't aware that SVG elements were so versatile when I cam across them this morning but if I can do the above it would be great.

Comment: yes it's possible. They do it at highcharts.com. You can just export the charts as svg. E.g.: at http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax you can click in the right top corner on what appears to be some lines under eacht other. There you have the option to export to SVG

Comment: awesome, at least I know its possible and therefore worth attempting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Button for downloading SVG in JavaScript & HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798877/button-for-downloading-svg-in-javascript-html)

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution using a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs):

```
var svg_root = document.getElementById('your_svg_root_element_here');
var svg_source = svg_root.outerHTML;
var svg_data_uri = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svg_source);
var link = document.getElementById('anchor_element');
link.setAttribute('href', svg_data_uri);
```

Although it worked, when clicking on the link, the browser stalled for a few seconds.

This seems to be the simplest solution and should be compatible with all modern browsers. However, it has some noticeable overhead. If someone else knows a different solution (maybe using blobs or something similar), please add here as another answer!